# Ruby curl Vs. httparty subscribe to a push API streaming

Tags: ruby, http, httparty

There is an API endpoint that I'm trying to subscribe to. When I do 
`curl -vL 'url'` I get streaming of data every 5 seconds and the connection stays open.

When I try to do the same thing from `httparty`

`response = HTTParty.get('url', follow_redirects: true)` just halts and doesn't do anything

when I do

`response = HTTParty.head('url', follow_redirects: true)`

I get

`ERR_596_SERVICE_NOT_FOUND`

Is there any recommendations on how do that from `httparty`, other gems or ruby in general?

Comment: `HTTParty` does not support persistent connections natively. You could take a look at [`persistent_httparty`](https://github.com/soupmatt/persistent_httparty) although I have never used this librabry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do that with `typhoeus` gem

```
request = Typhoeus::Request.new("url", followlocation: true)
            request.on_headers do |response|
              if response.code != 200
                raise "Request failed"
              end
            end
            request.on_body do |chunk|
              puts "****************"
              puts chunk.inspect
              puts "****************"
            end
            request.on_complete do |response|
              # downloaded_file.close
              # Note that response.body is ""
              puts "connection got closed maged"
            end
            request.run
```